# How to make an OptionButton ActiveX control change back-color to transparent?

Tags: excel, vba

I have added a few Excel ActiveX control option button to a sheet, and I need to change back-color to transparent. I used the following code but it is not working.

```
Sub removecolor()
    Dim cb As OptionButton
    For Each cb In ActiveSheet.OptionButton
        cb.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Next cb
End Sub
```

Would you please give me a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two points you should be aware of to make this work:

1. To access the OptionButton controls on the sheet, you need to iterate its `OLEObjects` collection.
2. An ActiveX control does not have an `Interior.ColorIndex` property. It does, however, have `BackColor` and `BackStyle` properties. You should be using `BackStyle` in this case in order to make the control transparent.

This should work:

```
Sub RemoveColor()
    For Each obj In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(obj.Object) = "OptionButton" Then
            obj.Object.BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

If you don't like providing the type name as a string, you can replace the condition with:

```
If TypeOf obj.Object Is MSForms.OptionButton Then   ' etc.
```